# Performance issues with @> operator in postgres 14

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, query, array

```
CREATE TABLE public.article (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    tags _text NULL,
    CONSTRAINT article_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I have the requirement to load articles that have a tag which is in a large list (at least 300 tags) from the DB:

```
SELECT * FROM public.cms_article where tags @> ARRAY['my_long_extra_long_tag_1', '...', '...', 'my_long_extra_long_tag_300'];
```

But I have a performance issue. Does anyone have experience with such requirement? Which index would be the best? The number of articles is less than 5000.

Comment: Did you try a GIN index on the array column? Please include `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.

Comment: thanks, GIN index helps

Comment: another question: is there reasonable number of maximum tags: I want to create composite tags. 1000, 10000?

Comment: Experiment. It will get slower and slower. Where is your pain point?

Comment: I am currently working on a concept how to search for articles with automatically composed tags. and here the question arises how many tags I can use. if I have for instance 5 Tags and combine them, I have more than 300 hundred permutations. for 7 tagsmore than 13000. which tag number would still practicable to handle

Comment: The number of permutations doesn't matter: PostgreSQL searches the index for all rows that contain the first element, then the second element, and so on, and returns those rows that come up every time. The search time will grow linearly with the length of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> articles that have a tag which is in a large list

This should translate to the [overlap operator **`&&`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html), not the containment operator `@>`:

```
... WHERE tags && ARRAY['my_extra_long_tag_1', '...', 'my_extra_long_tag_300'];
```

Support that with a GIN index like:

```
CREATE INDEX ON public.article USING gin (tags);
```

See:

- [Check if any of a given array of values are present in a Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20289634/939860)

Comment: Thanks,I need to take a closer look at the link with they overlap operator. :-)